FeedMe: glitches with importing assets into an assets field in a Matrix block (multisite instance)
I am an experienced user of FeedMe but I cannot get it to recognise an array of asset filenames in a Matrix block:

The FeedMe config sees my JSON node for the assets, and allows me to save it into the config.
The images cited already exist as assets
It recognises a sibling node for a text field in the same block.
On import it creates the block and the text, but ignores the assigned assets.

I have many times imported into Assets fields but not in a multisite context before.
Because it is multisite, I have tried making the image references absolute URLs as well, but that doesn’t help either.
As per the docs on importing into matrix I have JSON which looks like this:
{"entries":[
    {
        "fieldHandle":"value", 
        "matrixFieldHandle":{
            "block":[{
                "blockHandle": {
                    "text":"my text", 
                    "images":[
                        "filename.jpg"
                    ]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
]}


Turns out that, because the images field can work with assets in more than one folder, FeedMe only looks at the default folder assigned to the Assets field (in the Matrix block field setting).
So a way to resolve the above is to:

Constrain feed data to only one folder that the field can receive
Set the Assets field to that folder as its default
Run the feed
Revert the field to the preferred default.

It then works.

It would be great if FeedMe could search all folders (filesystems) assigned to the field.
